# specializes the std::swap algorithm for self defined container

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote my own vector and stack, they are class template,both works fine,now I want to Specializes the std::swap algorithm for my stack,so I defined a function template swap as friend of vector, it uses the swap inside vector.then I defined a swap member function in stack.but if I try to call that swap function, it can't compile. the vs2019 says the "the swap function doesn't accept two arguments". I thought the swap inside stack class would use argument dependent lookup,but it didn't do that.please help me,what is the right way to do it? thanks a lot. some code of vector and stack are below

Vector.h

```
  template<class Object>
    void swap(Vector<Object>& lhs, Vector<Object>& rhs) {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
    template<class Object>
    class Vector {
        //.....
        friend void swap<>(Vector<Object>& lhs, Vector<Object>& rhs);
    public:
        //...
        void swap(Vector &rhs){
        //....
        }
    }
```

Stack.h

```
 #include"Vector.h"
    template<class Object,class Container>
    class Stack {
    //......
    void swap(Stack &other) {
        swap(container, other.container);
    }
```

main.cpp

```
//....
int main() {
//....
    Stack<int,Vector<int>>s1,s2;
    s1.swap(s2);
}
//....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple case of name hiding: In the `Stack` class the name `swap` is `Stack::swap`.

If you want to use some other function you need to provide an explicit scope, as in

```
::swap(container, other.container);
```

Note the use of the `::` scoping operator to use the `swap` function from the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
void swap(Stack &other) {
    swap(container, other.container);
}
```

You are calling `swap` from itself.  You don't want that.  To make it so ADL finds the right swap function, you can try this:

```
// outside the class
template <typename T>
void MySwap(T& a1, T& a2) {
    using std::swap; // may not be needed in your case
    swap(a1, a2);
}

// in the class
void swap(Stack &other) {
    MySwap(container, other.container);
}
```

The name `swap` inside `MySwap` cannot possibly refer to `Stack::swap`, so it will use ADL to find the correct overload.

For more on why `using std::swap` is useful but possibly unnecessary in your case, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable